# WiX checking for .NET Framework 4

Tags: wix, windows-installer, .net-framework-version

I am trying to implement a check to see if the .NET framework is installed when running the installer.

I added the following:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

        <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
        <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again. Contact support at support@Swiftposter.com if you have further issues.">
            <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FUL]]>
        </Condition>
```

However, It always seems to result in false because it keeps stopping me even thou I have the full .NET framework installed (not just the client).

What does this happen?

Comment: NETFRAMEWORK40FUL (only one L in FULL) is intentionally here ?

Comment: Dang! Put that as a solution and I will mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

NETFRAMEWORK40FUL needs to have double L in FULL :)

Comment: well at least this fixed my CDATA line for .net 4.5    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.5.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
    </Condition>

Comment: Oddly, this made my day just b/c of the "$h1t happens" factor.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a list of .net versions :-)

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm